# Debugging a background script in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use some code from an open source library and I'm having some trouble logging to check where the code is failing.

In background.js:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, response) {
 // This does not show in my console
        console.log("request here");
    switch(request.type) {
        case 'enable?':
            objectName.onTabSelect(sender.tab.id);
            break;
        case 'search':
// Also does not log here
            console.log("Gets to first search item");
            var e = objectName.search(request.text);
            response(e);
            break;
        case 'open':
....
}
```

In content.js:

```
 //This shows in my console
    console.log("CHAR");
    console.log(char);
document.body.innerText.match(/[\u3400-\u9FBF]/g).forEach(function (char) {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({
        "type": "search",
        "text": char
    },
            function (char_return) {
//This shows in my console, but is an empty obj and why I want to debug
                console.log("char return");
                console.log(char_return);
            });

});
```

In main.js, a background script:

```
var objectName = {

...

search: function(text) {
// Does not log here. This is the area I REALLY want to log.
    console.log("Char search gets here");

    var entry = this.dict.wordSearch(text);
    if (entry != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < entry.data.length; i++) {
            var word = entry.data[i][1];
            if (this.dict.hasKeyword(word) && (entry.matchLen == word.length)) {
                // the final index should be the last one with the maximum length
                entry.grammar = { keyword: word, index: i };
            }
        }
    }

    return entry;

}
}
```

How do I log in a background script? It looks like maybe I should be using the `chrome.webRequest` method? Could this be because some of the methods are deprecated? I intend on updating them to the new methods once I've got the application working, but to get it working I need to log and see where it is failing.

This is the first Chrome extension I've built so I'm not quite sure how this works.

Comment: Are you sure you don't see the console.log output in the developer tools (console tab)? Did you try: `window.alert("something");` ?

Comment: Nope, nothing. Even with alerts. I tried throwing an alert into the search method above - nothing happened.

Comment: This might help: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/06/06/Quick-tip-for-debugging-Chrome-Extensions/

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!

Comment: There was an error in some code in the background and it was preventing other code from executing, hence why nothing was logging to the console. Please write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Can't I have to go... but feel free to post an answer and accept it - I think it would be helpful to other people in the future!